# Button not appearing in app using linear layout

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to have an image with a button next to it, when I run the code I just get the image at the left hand side of the screen with no button whether I have the image listed first or not.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/none"
        android:src="@drawable/oxwichpointtest" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="openGuide"
        android:text="@string/button_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE: Thanks for all the suggestions. I've tryed them all out but I got no change in my app layout so I suspect the problem lies in how I've set up the image in the .java file. I will try to change this and hopefully it will work, or I might add the code in here later if I'm still having problems. Thanks again, at least I know there's nothing majorly wrong with the layout.

Comment: use `android:layout_weight="1"` for imageview and check.

Comment: this work fines for me !

Comment: Lets start from this: android:layout_width="match_parent", android:orientation="horizontal" and xmlns:tools, are you using this? Also would be good to place android:weightSum="6"

Comment: can you post a screen shot of how it looks

Comment: I can't post an image since I dont have enough reputation points

Answer (score 0):

missing android:orientation attribute for the LinearLayout?

Comment: this should be a comment , not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a property in the Layout declaration.

**android:orientation="horinzontal"**

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horinzontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/none"
        android:src="@drawable/oxwichpointtest" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="openGuide"
        android:text="@string/button_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: default orientation == horizontal

Answer (score -1):

use Android:layout_weight="1" in the parent.

and than assign the portion of the weight as you desire to imageview and button!Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom" android:layout_weight="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"

    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/none"
    android:src="@drawable/oxwichpointtest" android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"

    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="openGuide"
    android:text="@string/button_text" android:layout_weight="0.5"/></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make it as the answer if it fulfill your requirement

Comment: use proper dp values in width